# SSIS Package FAILS in DTExec.exe "There was an error in the Precedence Constraint"

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017, ssms

I need to create a Package that, if doesn't find any rows on a certain table, execute another package.

In order to get that working, I created an SQL Task to check rows, a proper variable, and  an expression. If I execute the package inside the SSIS, It works perfectly fine, but if I use the command DTExec.exe on a .BAT, It fails saying that theres an error on the "PRECEDENT CONSTRAINT".

Any Idea what is going on?

thanks a lot!

1ºEDIT:

Here are the pictures with the pipeline and the error. At first I th
ought that maybe my Variable was wrong, but as you can see, even with a statement as if we are in 2023, just continue the pipeline, still fails.

[image: Error]

[image: Pipeline]

Thanks!!

Comment: It is better to use Integration Services Catalog.

Comment: What is the _exact_ error? copy paste it please. If you are using an expression in your constraint, then possibly an unexpected value is causing the expression to fail. Depending on what you are doing, this is probably much more simply achieved in pure T-SQL

Comment: Peel off the .bat file and just run the dtexec "plain". I'd use a command line like `dtexec.exe /file .\MyPackage.dtsx /rep EIW` and then copy paste the entire output back into your question and we'll be able to tell you what's awry

Comment: Works for me. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfnbZ.png What catches my eye is the "Class not registered" line in the Warnings section. And the "source" is "Package_ET_CORE_SF_CASO_FAILURE"  but we don't see that in the visible Control Flow. Is it possible there's more to this simple package than shown - say error handling? Or, if that Execute Package Task is referencing a project package, then are you invoking the dtexec correctly? That's a reason for asking to see the raw `dtexec` call as a project deployment model would use a different set of command line values

Comment: billinkc, I cannot get the log that you are requesting me. Any idea what could be wrong? 

Here's the new bat that im executing:

@ECHO OFF
CLS
ECHO You are about to execute the TestPackage SSIS package
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /File "C:\BI_BatchProcess\Package_ET_CORE_SF_PRO_CASO_FAILURE.dtsx" /rep EIW
ECHO Done
EXIT 0

Btw, I created a NEW package, and with just 2 SQL tasks, as "SELECT COUNT(*) from Table", and I still get the same error.

Comment: I'm always here. Are you using the Package Deployment Model or a Project Deployment Model? Right click on the Project node in Visual Studio and there should be either "Convert to Package Deployment Model" or "Convert to Project Deployment Model" option

Comment: While I support batch scripts for ensuring repeatable processes, I find it effective to get single line commands working perfect before automating them. Is there something specific about having the commands in a batch file that you're then executing that we need to be aware of (that could be influencing the behaviour you're experience compared to me). While unlikely to be the issue, you can patch that machine's SQL Server instance. Tooling is showing 14.0.3026 - released 2018-05-23 and current is 14.0.3456 released 2022-09-20

Comment: hi @billinkc ! It's worth noting that we have several identical bats that have been working (and still) perfectly fine.
On the other hand, this demo package only fails if I write a conditional expression in the Precedence Constrain. If I just connect it as the usual way, works fine.

The idea of update the Server Instance is good, however it's a bit hard as I have to request it to the IT team.

Finally, each of the packages that we have says "Convert to Package Deployment Model".

thanks!!

Comment: As you're using the project deployment model, the syntax for dtexec should change to `dtexec /proj .\bin\Development\SO_Trash.ispac /pack SO_75197519.dtsx` The `/proj` argument is where the .ispac file is located and then `/pack` ties to the actual package

Comment: The other thing to test is create a package that is two sequence containers joined by the same troublesome precedent constraint and see whether that also suffers from the same error.

Comment: The weird thing is that we currently have like 9 bats working, and all of them have the same syntax.
Related to your other question, I've also created a complete new package, with 2 new task, and got the same output. It's so annoying!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a solution. Basically, if anyone has a similar problem, you must REPAIR your SQL SERVER installation. As I was using Visual Studio Data Tools 2017, I thought that we didn't have it installed, so I didn't care, but YES, STILL, for using DTEXEC you need SQL SERVER.